# Working through NeHe tutorials with Python

Tags: opengl

http://nehe.gamedev.net/ The tutorials wirtten here are done in C++. But if I have the right understanding of OpenGL, then OpenGL programming can be done in many languages through binding. This means that all the code at the tutorial can be implemented in Python. Is this correct?

Comment: Yup. OpenGL is OpenGL. There may be some subtle differences, but general logic stays the same. Note however, that nehe tutorials are quite outdated.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don't waste time on the tutorials marked 'Legacy Tutorials'. I'm not sure if NEHE has anything new worth reading, but the legacy tutorials teach an extremely outdated version of OpenGL that you would be wise not to waste your time on.

Answer (score 1):

PyOpenGL is a Python binding to OpenGL which is worth checking out. Its homepage is [PyOpenGL -- The Python OpenGL Binding](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/).

That website includes discussion on adapting several NeHe tutorial examples to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from some window and OpenGL context handling, all the code should be able to be fully ported to Python.